# How to extract only numbers from web from <td> attribute with no identificator( by beautiful soup)

Tags: python, search, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, int

After get response to my http request, i need to identify ID in response and asign value to it.
Basicly i do the program which loads page, search product by ID and then read the content of webpage and assign actual stock value for this product.

```
test = s.get(test)
soup = BeautifulSoup(test.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table",class_="table")
code = table.find("small",class_="code")

listTd=table.findAll("td") #iam able to find all td where are data saved.
#Here i don´t know how to identify the corrrect td which contains only int values ( it pressents actual number of products on stock, i need extract that).#


#Here is response from web:
[<td>
<a href="/Products/19321">
<small class="code">Code: 64SPW.100</small>
<span class="product_description">
<span class="description">Ø10x22x72 ØG.10</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>, <td>
                        72.37 EUR/NP
                        <br/>
<span class="iva">(excluding VAT 0%)</span>
</td>, <td>
                        55%
                    </td>, <td>
                        32.57 EUR/NP
                        <br/>
<span class="iva">(excluding VAT 0%)</span>
</td>, <td>
44                    </td>, <td class="shopping">
<div class="add_to_cart">
<form action="/Products/19321/AddToCart?returnUrl=%2FProducts%2FSearch%3Fquery%3D64SPW.100" method="post"> <div class="input-append">
<input autocomplete="off" class="span1" name="quantity" type="text" value="1"/>
<span class="add-on">NP</span>
</div>
<input class="btn btn-primary loader" type="submit" value="Add to cart"/>
</form>
</div>
</td>, <td>
<a href="/Products/19322">
<small class="code">Code: 64SPW.100C</small>
<span class="product_description">
<span class="description">Ø10x22x72 ØG.10 Cer-A</span>
</span>
</a>
</td>, <td>
                        79.44 EUR/NP
                        <br/>
<span class="iva">(excluding VAT 0%)</span>
</td>, <td>
                        55%
                    </td>, <td>
                        35.75 EUR/NP
                        <br/>
<span class="iva">(excluding VAT 0%)</span>
</td>, <td>
8                    </td>,
```

as you can see in the code : Code: 64SPW.100 and it is due to that i take 64SPW.100 value and search it on web and have to somehow link it with value 44. But there is no identificator according which i can find this value and assign to proper code which was searched
Is there anyway how to do that?

Is here any possible way how to link Code : "value" with proper value in  44 <\td> ? I wasn´t able to write rullers, which will find  attributes after proper Code: 64SPW.100 and identify that in this  attribute is only int number and assign it to the code?

So for every code in response should be clear, that if there will be sequence Code:64SP.100 will be linked with the closest sequence <.td> include only int numbers <\td>

Comment: Can you share the original url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to find the next `<td>` tag with only integers in it.

- You can use a [regular expression as filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression).
- [find_next](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) -  Finds the next element matching the filters.

```
code.find_next('td', text=re.compile(r'^[\n\s]*\d+[\n\s]*$')
```

You may need to tweak  the regex for your specific case. I am only matching for a positive integers with spaces or newlines.

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed. I tried to regular expresion to filter it, but i wasn´t able to write that filter on my own.